# Intermediate Frequency in FM receiver

Tags: rf, radio, receiver, frequency-modulation

I have question about specifically FM radio receiver that use the heterodyne principle:

How Intermediate Frequency, that's fixed in one frequency (10.7 Mhz), works in FM receivers if FM radios need frequency modulation to pass a useful signal?

Does the mixer with local oscillator in a FM receiver pass a bandwidth or just one frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incoming radio signal isn't mixed down to exactly 10.7 MHz, that would be pointless. Rather, the incoming signal (which varies in frequency) is mixed with a stable local oscillator; the result is a signal that has the same frequency variations but centered around 10.7 MHz.

This intermediate frequency is filtered through either tuned LC circuits or a ceramic resonator, but these circuits are not so narrow-banded that the frequency deviation is lost. The frequency swing of commercial FM stations is +- 75 kHz anyway, or 0.075 MHz, less than 1% of the IF frequency.

Comment: Sure? I belive it's +/-75kHz. Also is IM a typo for IF?

Comment: @carloc You are correct, it's 150 kHz total. Text corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The whole bandwidth of the fm signal is mixed down to the intermediate frequency. Just simple multiplication of the radio signal and the local oscillator achieves this.